# Why is this case when not working properly?

Tags: ruby, case

```
  if ( item::class == RPG::Weapon )
    print "yup"
  end
  case item::class
  when RPG::Item
    type = 0
  when RPG::Weapon
    type = 1
  when RPG::Armor
    type = 2
  else
    type = 10
  end
```

I'm new to Ruby. The if statement runs fine and prints "yup", but the case statement isn't working properly and sets type to 10. Am I blind to something or what?

Comment: `case` uses === not ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) tests if the argument is an instance of `self`. `item.class` can never be an instance of anything but [`Class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Class.html), in particular, it will never be an instance of either `RPG::Weapon` or `RPG::Armor`, therefore none of the `when` branches will ever match and you will always get the `else` branch.

By the way: using the namespace resolution operator `::` for message sends instead of the message sending operator `.` is *extremely* un-idiomatic and confusing (and won't work for methods whose name starts with an uppercase character). In fact, I believe matz considers adding this feature to Ruby a mistake.

Note also that `case` is an expression, in fact, *everything* in Ruby is an expression.

I would write the code as follows:

```
type = case item
  when RPG::Item
    0
  when RPG::Weapon
    1
  when RPG::Armor
    2
  else
    10
end
```

However, in general, conditionals are a code smell. Ruby is an object-oriented language, polymorphism (i.e. method dispatching based on the type of `self`) is [all the conditional you need](http://antiifcampaign.com/)! In fact, in this very example, you are manually examining the class of `item` in order to determine its type, but that is *exactly* what method dispatch does anyway! Personally, I would [refactor](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) this code like this:

```
class RPG::Item
  def type
    0
  end
end

class RPG::Weapon
  def type
    1
  end
end

class RPG::Armor
  def type
    2
  end
end

class RPG::Object # or whatever your baseclass is
  def type
    10
  end
end
```

Now when you add a new kind of game object, you don't have to modify your existing code by adding a new branch to your `case` expression. You just add the new class, without needing to modify any existing code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am a bit confused cause I'm unsure of a few things and I just realized something. The script that I'm testing is one that I'm using for a game engine called RPG Maker. In the engine there's a Base_Item script and in it they have a variable called @class( I just realized that they're using the reserved word class). Are they overriding the word class or something like that? They are setting the "variable" class to "RPG::Weapon" and etc.. Are they actually changing the type of class it is or is it just a variable? Sorry for asking you something that's not really your business.

Comment: Using just "item" instead of "item::class" works fine by the way, but I just wanted to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just `case item` will be sufficient - no need for `case item::class`.

Case matching in Ruby is done with a fuzzy matching (`===`) algorithm that doesn't need such specific clauses.